# How to match any of these words, but just the last one in the list with .NET Regex

Tags: regex, match

I'm using .Net Regex, I'm trying to match any of these words

```
call from, call to, call ended, no answer, send video message
```

but just the last one in this list (the list come from clipboard, there are CRLF after each line)

```
I know
[3/10/2015 11:18:11 PM] John Gerome: you know
[3/10/2015 11:20:32 PM] John Gerome: tell me
[2/25/2015 4:23:23 PM] *** Call from John Gerome ***
[2/25/2015 5:36:38 PM] *** Call ended, duration 1:13:15 ***
[2/2/2015 5:55:35 PM] *** Call to John Gerome ***
[2/2/2015 7:01:17 PM] *** Call ended, duration 1:05:34 ***
[3/10/2015 11:16:46 PM] *** Call to John Gerome, no answer.
Send video message ***
[3/10/2015 11:18:11 PM] John Gerome: say something
[3/10/2015 11:20:32 PM] John Gerome: Bob
[3/10/2015 11:20:32 PM] John Gerome: are you there
```

Is there any way to do this with only one regex code???? perhaps replace??

So far I have do this...

```
(Call (from|to|ended)|no answer|Send video message)
```

So the final output in this particular case should be "send video message" (whithout quotes) it may vary depending on which is the last word matched in the list (the one at the bottom).

Thanks Advanced.

Comment: what is the exact output you expect?

Comment: The last element (`Send video message`) or the last matched line?

Comment: the last element: ___Send video message___ THanks

Comment: Try `(? <=^|\*{3}\s*).*(?=\s*\*{3})` with RightToLeft and Multilene option and limit to  1 match.

Comment: nothing, doesn't work, even with RtoL and multiline option enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(? <=^.*|\*{5}\s*).*{1}(?=\s*\*{4})
```

using Multiline, and full matches.